# Where to configure Hudson node disk/temp space thresholds?

Tags: hudson, config

I am currently running a Hudson instance on a VM slice.  As I don't have a need to run more than a couple small applications from it, I'm minimizing how much space I devote to it.  The sizes I've defined for this slice seem fine to me, however Hudson seems to have it's own ideas on what are considered minimum disk and temp space thresholds.

[image: Only place I know where to configure a threshold (turn on/off, really)]

And then I look at the Node and I see the following:
[image: Master Node claims 546MB is too little to work with.]

546MB does not seem like *too little* space for running my small number of applications, but Hudson seems to disagree.  Is there any place I can configure Hudson to redefine what it considers **too low** for disk and temp space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Hudson 1.339 it is configurable.
See here http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Features+controlled+by+system+properties

The property is called
hudson.diagnosis.HudsonHomeDiskUsageChecker.freeSpaceTheshold

Answer (score 17):

It is configurable from the web interface:

> Hudson > Nodes > Configure > Preventive Node Monitoring > Free Disk Space (defaulted to 1GB)

You might also want to change Free Temp Space whilst you're there.

Be aware that you'll need to give Hudson some time to pick up on the change after you save it. So if the free disk space warning doesn't disappear as soon as you return to the nodes page, don't worry - the disk space monitor only runs once an hour.

Answer (score 2):

It's not configurable.  Just turn off the monitors, so your nodes stay online.

See issue [HUDSON-2552](http://issues.hudson-ci.org/browse/HUDSON-2552) for a fix.  The code is not yet part of Hudson though.