# Jenkins running on AWS EC2 running out of disk space despite upgrading the memory size

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I have Jenkins running on an ec2 instance.  The main build server had gone offline due to "Out of Disk space".  I upgraded the ec2 instance to a larger instance type (moving from a .large instance with 4GB of memory to a .xlarge with 8GB of memory)

[image]

However, after upgrading the instance to have more memory, the Free Disk Space still showed the same amount, and instead I reduced the Free Space Threshold to enable the master node to get back online.  (As outlined here: [how to solve jenkins 'Disk space is too low' issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325982/how-to-solve-jenkins-disk-space-is-too-low-issue/41283451))

Why did the Free Disk Space remain the same despite increasing the memory space of the instance?  Is there a way that I can allocate more memory to the Jenkins via some server settings?

Comment: Please see [What is the difference between memory and disk storage?](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahtx), or other Google searches for the difference between these two very different concepts. Sounds like you actually want to increase the size of your EBS volume.

Comment: After following @dmulter's advice, you might want to take a look at the [aws guide to resizing a volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modify-volume.html)

Answer (score 1):

RAM and Disk Space are not the same thing. You will need to resize the EBS volume, then expand the partition/filesystem to use the additional space.

Expanding the partition/filesystem is OS-specific. Here is the procedure for Linux. I am assuming you are running Linux on your server based on the screenshot.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-modify-volume.html